# Can a folder that is in a Git repo be imported into Eclipse if it is not part of a project?

Tags: eclipse, git

There is a folder in a Git repo which holds a bunch of sql scripts but the folder is not part of any project. When I try to create a folder in Eclipse it seems to require that I specify an existing project for it to be a subfolder of. Is that always required or can a folder exist at the same level as the projects, with no project for it to be under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in an Eclipse workspace must be in a project. Folders cannot be at the same level as a project.

Comment: This implies to me then that if a Git repo has files that are not part of a project, those files can't be edited/checked out/checked-in using Eclipse. Is this correct? Or at least not in a natural/convenient way?

Comment: I don't use Git so I can't say for sure but I think you are correct.